# How much more efficient would human metabolism be if fat were denser?

Tags: internal-consistency, metabolism

If the density of fat were raised to about a density of 3g/mm, how would human metabolism be affected? Would it be massively improved, or is there some fatal flaw I'm not taking into account?

Comment: why do you expect density to influence the metabolism?

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica Since it could take up less space, there is much more leeway for the amount of fat needed to start causing organ shutdown due to cramping and being constricted.

Comment: @GreenieE.-ReinstateMonica have you seen the amount of fat that the human body is able to carry and continue functioning?

Comment: @StarfishPrime All too well

Comment: Please can you clarify your units what are g/mm?

Comment: @Slarty g/mm^3 presumably so 1 mm^3 of fat would weigh one gram.

Comment: What do you mean by "the density of fat were raised"? The density of fat is an intrinsic property of fat, you cannot really play with it. That much denser substance is not fat, it is something else; and we need to know *what* something else it is, in order to provide a sensible answer.

Comment: Bad things will happen, we already have this it is called saturated fats, they pack tighter resulting in higher density, but also a stiffer cell membrane as they are incorporated, a diet of only high density fats is very bad for you.

Comment: If you are talking about energy density, then nothing will change the limiting factor for human metabolism is not the metabolite, but oxygen availability and the fact the brain can't metabolize fats.

Answer (score 3):

**Metabolism of nutrients occurs on the molecular level.  The density of those molecules does not affect how the individual molecules are processed.**

I am making 2 assumptions: metabolism refers to

> the chemical processes that occur within a living organism in order to
>   maintain life.

and not some looser sense of the word "metabolism", like general health status.

I will assume also that because these molecules are still fat but are packed in some ultra dense way, they will be metabolized as fat.

An analogy would be the sugar molecules in lemonade.  They are not packed very densely, dissolved in the liquid.  Now contrast that to the sugar molecules in honey.  It is almost pure sugar, and the molecules are much more dense.  The caloric density of honey is much greater than that of lemonade and by caloric density I mean calories of energy your body derives by metabolizing these substances.  The metabolic processes used on the sugars are the same for honey and for lemonade.

Starch is a dense way of packing sugar.  Maybe your super dense fat is a new dense way of packing fat?  I could imagine that being useful evolutionarily for seeds and nuts, which is where I would expect to find superdense fats in nature.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you make 3g fit into 1 cubic mm. Do you make the atoms smaller and denser? Or do you push normal atoms together with incredible force? Either way it would not end well. Smaller atoms would not be able to be metabolised and highly pressurised normal matter would pose difficulties in expansion that would do serious damage to organs when the time came to metabolise it.

But regardless of that no humans would be able to survive with fat at 3g/cubic mm. 3g/cubic mm = 3kg/cubic cm = 3tons/litre. As most people would have 10-20kg of fat in their bodies they would all be pinned to the floor under the weight and their hearts would give out.